# How does git set parent number during a merge

Tags: git

Is it true that, when doing a merge, git always set current commit as parent number 1, and other commits as parent 2, 3, ...?

For example, if I'm on branch `master` and want to merge independent branches `feature-01` and `feature-02`:

```
git checkout master
git merge feature-01 feature-02
```

Is it true that git will always set old `master` as parent 1, and `feature-01` as parent 2, and `feature-02` as parent 3?

Comment: Yes, that is true for `git merge` and its eventual `git commit`. You can defeat this (if you intend to do so) through the use of the plumbing commands, but the norm is to make sure that the first parent is always the commit that was `HEAD` when you ran `git merge`.

Comment: @torek Any chance of providing a document or spec as proof?

Comment: Nope. Look at the source instead. The first parent comes from `HEAD`; the alternate parents come from `MERGE_HEAD`. Start at https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c/builtin/commit.c#L1478 and https://github.com/git/git/blob/e3a80781f5932f5fea12a49eb06f3ade4ed8945c/builtin/commit.c#L1504 and read forward from there. Note that `--amend` is different (but does not conclude a merge).

Comment: To verify that the rest of the commits come in the right order, you'll need to check that `git merge` writes `MERGE_HEAD` in the right order. I believe it does but will leave finding the code to you. The documentation probably *ought* to say these things, but obviously doesn't.

Comment: @torek Looks like `commit_list_append` appends current head first during a merge. It'd be good if they document this behavior in man page if they really mean to keep the order.

Comment: The `--first-parent` option would be useless if they did not maintain this invariant, so it's kind of implied, but I do agree that it should be explicitly documented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in case of an [octopus merge](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge-ltcommitgt82308203).

The [first parent is particular has a dedicated flag in `git log`: --first-parent](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#git-log---first-parent) to follow the main line of code (seen also in [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---min-parentsltnumbergt)).

> This option can give a better overview when viewing the evolution of a particular topic branch, because merges into a topic branch tend to be only about adjusting to updated upstream from time to time, and this option allows you to ignore the individual commits brought in to your history by such a merge.

Comment: The man page says `--first-parent` follows first parent commit but doesn't say which commit is assigned as first commit in case of an octopus merge?

Comment: git rev-list mentions: "--max-parents=1 is the same as --no-merges": first parent is where you do the merge. the other parents are what you are merging to (the first parent)